# Multi-dimentional tables in Lua

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, lua

I am new to Lua and I am trying to create a small app to read out adc values. The point here is that I am trying to assign values from one table to another with the following code but it really does not work (no errors, just does nothing):

```
-- Setting output GPIO pins
multip = {  sc0 = 0,  sc1 = 3,  sc2 = 4 }
for k3,v3 in pairs(multip) do gpio.mode(v3, gpio.OUTPUT) end

-- Assigning ADC channels
HIHs = {
        hum1 = {
                sc0 = gpio.HIGH,
                sc1 = gpio.LOW,
                sc2 = gpio.HIGH
        },
        hum2 = {
                sc0 = gpio.LOW,
                sc1 = gpio.HIGH,
                sc2 = gpio.HIGH
        },
        hum3 = {
                sc0 = gpio.HIGH,
                sc1 = gpio.HIGH,
                sc2 = gpio.HIGH
        }
}

-- Sequentially access each channel and read value
for g,t in pairs(HIHs) do
    print("---------- Setting Humidity sensor " .. g .. " ----------")
    for k4,v4 in pairs(multip) do 
        print("Writing pin " .. k4 .. " to " .. tostring(t[k4]))
        gpio.write(v4, t[k4])   
    end
    print("ADC Value: "..adc.read(0))
end
```

The very strange part is that if i do:

```
for k1,v1 in pairs(HIHs) do for k2,v2 in pairs(v1) do print(k1,k2,v2) end end
```

I am not even getting the HIHs table in the correct order, it starts printing from the second element:

```
hum2    sc0 0
hum2    sc1 1
hum2    sc2 1
hum3    sc0 1
hum3    sc1 1
hum3    sc2 1
hum1    sc0 1
hum1    sc1 0
hum1    sc2 1
```

What is wrong with this code? Why can't I access my table and shouldn't it print it in order? Unless I am clearly missing something out very very basic in Lua understanding....

Thanks for any help.... :)

Comment: the sequencing is normal, Lua tables are unordered so any appearances of ordered data is coincidental. also dont do `ipairs(HIHs)` do `pairs(HIHs)`

Comment: Yes, thanks it explains why i get the data in not the order I would expect. Sorry for the ipairs that's was just a typo, i actually use pairs.

Answer (score -2):

Please note I don't know the details of your application (if your approach is correct), so I am giving general advice.

Instead of:

```
-- Setting output GPIO pins
multip = {  sc0 = 0,  sc1 = 3,  sc2 = 4 }
for k3,v3 in pairs(multip) do gpio.mode(v3, gpio.OUTPUT) end
```

You can use:

```
-- Setting output GPIO pins
multip = {{"sc0",0},{"sc1",3},{"sc2",4}}
for k,v in ipairs(multip) do gpio.mode(v[2], gpio.OUTPUT) end
```

Instead of:

```
-- Assigning ADC channels
HIHs = {
        hum1 = {
                sc0 = gpio.HIGH,
                sc1 = gpio.LOW,
                sc2 = gpio.HIGH
        },
        hum2 = {
                sc0 = gpio.LOW,
                sc1 = gpio.HIGH,
                sc2 = gpio.HIGH
        },
        hum3 = {
                sc0 = gpio.HIGH,
                sc1 = gpio.HIGH,
                sc2 = gpio.HIGH
        }
}
```

You may want to do:

```
HIHs = {}
-- hum1
HIHs[1] = {}
HIHs[1][1] = gpio.HIGH
HIHs[1][2] = gpio.LOW
HIHs[1][3] = gpio.HIGH
-- hum2
HIHs[2] = {}
HIHs[2][1] = gpio.HIGH
HIHs[2][2] = gpio.LOW
HIHs[2][3] = gpio.HIGH
-- hum3
HIHs[3] = {}
HIHs[3][1] = gpio.HIGH
HIHs[3][2] = gpio.LOW
HIHs[3][3] = gpio.HIGH
```

This way you can easily iterate over a chosen order:

```
-- For each HIH
for iHIH=1,#HIHs do
    -- For each sc
    for iSC=1,#HIHs[iHIH] do
        local pin = multip[iSC][2]
        local state = HIH[iHIH][iSC]
        print("Writing pin " .. tostring(pin) .. " to " .. tostring(state))
        gpio.write(pin, state)
    end
end
```

The order should be:

```
hum1    sc0
hum1    sc1
...
hum3    sc0
hum3    sc2
hum3    sc3
```

Comment: What exactly was wrong with their original code is not clear in your answer. You should explain why, they want to do what you have suggested as opposed to what they were doing before.

Comment: I kind of get why my code does not wok now: Lua would expect me to call a table element using its key value within double quotes when the key is a string. In my code, by using `t[k4]`, `k4` is a string but is not in double quotes, hence the returned value is nil. 
The question though remains: if I replace the `t[k4]` with `t[string.format("\"%s\"", k4)]` shouldn't it work?

Comment: @LuminociterFos `t[k4]` is perfectly fine. the only issue with your code was that you expected a table to have an order which is not the case unless you're using numeric keys.

Comment: @LuminociterFos I've edited, see if it makes more sense now. Unfortunately I do not not the details of your application to judge.

Comment: @LuminociterFos If you're working with a raspberry pi or something, look for a tutorial and try to reproduce it first. Then slowly modify it to fit your needs. Search for existing code that accomplishes what you want as well.

Comment: @Real you should not recommend using `pairs` here as the traversion order is not specified. it will work often but it is not safe. use `ipairs` or a numeric for loop.

Comment: @Piglet: ipairs is not suitable in this context. pairs is more suitable since actually ordering is not of the essence but keying is and ipairs only works with integer keys.
Also it's not a raspberry pi, its a dedicated on-off device I designed for a specific application but is based on NodeMCU firmware. The original code i posted actually works, it was the ordering issue i did not expect...

Comment: @LuminociterFos it is suitable in this answers code. please note that this was a comment on this answer not on your code where ipairs wouldn't work.

Comment: @LuminociterFos I've made some changes, I believe the code should work now, feel free to ask clarifications.